# how can i change back the original color of JButton when i clicked it again?

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, jbutton, background-color

the code below is how i change my *JButton* color to magenta. what i wanted to do is when i click the same button again i want it to go back to its normal color. I've tried searching in google but i can't seem to find the right answer for this problem. if you guys have any suggestion please let me know. thank you.

```
    Object source = e.getSource();
    int s=0;

    if (source instanceof Component) {
        ((Component)source).setBackground(Color.magenta);
        s=0;

    }
    </i>
```

Comment: have you tried to use a counter and check if the numer is odd or even? and then change the color depending on this?

Comment: try something like ((Component)source).setBackground((((Component)source).getBackground()==Color.magenta)?Color.blue:Color.magenta) where you can switch blue to whatever color

Comment: Whats the problem? Do you have the problem where/when to change to color back, or is the problem which color is the orginal color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check what's color right now:

```
if (((Component)source).getBackground().equals(Color.magenta)){
    ((Component)source).setBackground(null);
} else {
    ((Component)source).setBackground(Color.magenta);
    s=0;
}
```

null returns JButton to default color

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean switcher = false;
if (source instanceof Component) {
        if(switcher)((Component)source).setBackground(Color.OLDCOLOR);
        else ((Component)source).setBackground(Color.magenta);

        switcher = switcher?false:true;

    }
```

Comment: you need no switcher. If the color is the old one, the new has to be used, else the old one

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement your own `JButton`?

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {

    private Color on;
    private Color off;
    private boolean isOn = false;

    public void setOnColor(Color on) {
        this.on = on;
    }

    public void setOffColor(Color off) {
        this.off = off;
    }

    public void switchColor() {
        if (this.isOn)
            super.setBackground(this.on);
        else
            super.setBackground(this.off);
        this.isOn = !this.isOn;
    }
}
```

When initializing the button

```
MyButton b = new MyButton();
b.setOffColor(null);
b.setOnColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

In the event you can then do

```
Object source = e.getSource();

if (source instanceof MyButton) {
    ((MyButton)source).switchColor();
}
```